Dart. Instance of 'JSArray<dynamic>': type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<double>'
Trying to parse data from json to Map<double, double>, but stuck with this error

DartError: TypeError: Instance of 'JSArray': type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'

in the end i need 'data' as Map<double, double> but the problem remains no matter what methods i use.
Here is the simpliest code:
 final jsonData = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/data/dataTest.json');
    final data = json.decode(jsonData);
    final modules = data['modules'];
    final steps = modules['data'];
    print(steps);

    final List<double> keys =
        steps.keys.map((e) => double.parse(e)).toList();

The json example:
{
    "modules": {
        "name": "name1",
        "data": {
            "1": "450",
            "2": "26.8",
            "4": "12.4",
            "3.07": "14",
            "1.25": "79",
            "1.53": "47.5",
            "2.5": "18.8",
            "1.86": "30.2",
            "1.66": "43.2"
        }
    }
}


In object 'data' key like "1" and "2" are integers, and not directly converted to double. Convert the keys to double and try again with your code.

You can use Map.map() to convert from the Map<String, dynamic> to a Map<double, double> as follows:
  final steps = modules['data'] as Map<String, dynamic>; // let the compiler know what type of map it already is

  final result = steps.map<double, double>(
      (k, v) => MapEntry(double.parse(k), double.parse(v)));

  print(result.runtimeType); // Map<double, double>


thank you very much, a few things I was missing. Now it works as intended.
